# Can we find a function that satisfies these conditions?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $$
f (x)  := \begin{cases} 
\lceil{x}\rceil  &\mbox{for } x \le 1 \\[8pt]
\lceil{2x}\rceil-1 &  \mbox{for } x > 1 
\end{cases}
$$
be a function and $n$ be a positive integer number. We are given a set of positive real numbers $A = \{a_1, \dots, a_n\}$. We want to find an $\varepsilon > 0$ and a function $g (x)$ such that

$$
\begin{cases} 
g(a_i) \le a_i  &\mbox{$\forall a_i \in A$ } \\
f(g(a_i)) = f(a_i) &  \mbox{$\forall a_i \in A$}\\
f(g(a_i) - \varepsilon) < f (g(a_i)) &  \mbox{$\forall a_i\in A$}
\end{cases}
$$

By trial and error, I ended up with

$$
g(a_i)  = \begin{cases} 
a_i-1+\varepsilon  &\mbox{For $a_i \in A$ and integer} \\
\lfloor{a_i}\rfloor + \varepsilon &  \mbox{For $a_i \in A$ and not integer}.
\end{cases}
$$
in which $\varepsilon$ could be any positive real number such that $$
\varepsilon \le \frac{ \displaystyle\min_{i=1,\dots,n} \{a_i - \lfloor {a_i}\rfloor \colon a_i - \lfloor {a_i}\rfloor > 0 \} }{2}
$$
Unfortunately it does not necessarily satisfy the second condition.

So what do you think? Is there a function $g(x)$ that satisfies those conditions?

**Edit:**

I want to show that we can always find an $\varepsilon  \to 0$ for any given set $A$. Basically, I am looking for an upper bound for $\varepsilon$ which is less than one. As is mentioned in one of the answers, for $\varepsilon > 1$ we can simply take $g(a_i)=a_i$ and $\varepsilon = 2$.

Comment: I'm just curious: why would someone want a function like this?

Comment: I believe that if I find such a function $g(\cdot)$, then I can use it to find an optimal solution for the optimization problem$$
\begin{align}
 \max_{x_1,\dots,x_n} ~~ & \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i) && \\
 \text{subject to}\ \ \ & \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} \le b && \\
 & 0 \le x_{i} \le a_i && \forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\}.
\end{align}
$$
In this problem, $b>0$ is a given parameter and $x_i$ is a decision variable. The function $f(\cdot)$ is the one that I introduced in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $J$ be the set of *jumps* of $f$. For clarification, this is

$$J=\{1-n\mid n\in\Bbb N_0\}\cup\{1+n/2\mid n\in\Bbb N_0\}.$$

The idea is to move any $a$ sufficiently close to its closest jump below so that it still stays in between the same jumps as before, but any movement by $\epsilon$ or more will push it over the cliff and make $f$ decrease. This will work for all $\epsilon>0$.

Let $\lfloor a\rfloor'_J$ denote the biggest number $j\in J$ which is smaller than $a$. Then

$$g(a)=\min(a,\lfloor a\rfloor'_J+\epsilon/2)$$

will do it. You said nothing about any continuity requirements on $g$, but if $A$ is not too badly behaved (e.g. finite or without limit points), then you can redefine $g$ on $\Bbb R-A$ arbitrarily to make it continuous (or even differentiable etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Just take $g(a_i)=a_i$ and $\epsilon = 10^{1000}$ (or, less dramatically, $\epsilon = 2$ should do it).

Comment: Thanks Jack. Your answer shows that there exists an $\epsilon > 1$ that satisfies the condition. If I knew about this I would modify the question saying that we must have $\epsilon < 1$. Basically, I want to show that we can always find an $\epsilon  \to 0$. In other words, I am looking for an upper bound for $\epsilon$ which is less than one!

Comment: @Opt Well, are you looking for an $\epsilon$ less than one, or are you looking for an arbitrarily small $\epsilon$? Those are very different questions.

Comment: I'm looking for an arbitrarily small $\epsilon$, but I think if we can find an upper bound for  $\epsilon$ which is less than one that should do?